# Time gets changed when formatting date to string in a particular format in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a date with value "Sat Nov 14 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015".I need to convert this variable to a string date with format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss".For that i used the below code,

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String date=dtf.format(reDate);
```

where reDate has the value "Sat Nov 14 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015".But after conversion i got the value as "2015-11-14 12:00:00".The time "00:00:00" get changed to "12:00:00".How that happens? I need to get the exact time after conversion.That is the result as "2015-11-14 00:00:00".How to do that? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `HH` instead of `hh` as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date=dtf.format(reDate);
```